# Why python multiprocessing in this code is slower?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have this sample code. I'm making some math computation (graph theory) and I want to increase the speed so I decided to go with multiprocessing but surprisingly the same code runs even slower than the single process version.

I expect that if you have a list and you split it in half and start two processes it should take approximately half time. I don't think I have some synchronization issue so why the hell is this so slow?

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def do_work(queue, aList):

    for elem in aList:
        newList.append(a_math_function(elem))

    queue.put(max(newList))
    return max(newList)

def foo():

    #I have let's say aList with 100000 objects

    q1 = Queue(); q2 = Queue()

    p1 = Process(target=do_work, args=[q1, aList[0: size/2])])
    p2 = Process(target=do_work, args=[q2, aList[size/2+1: size])])

    p1.start(); p2.start()
    p1.join(); p2.join()

    print(max(q1.get(),q2.get())
```

Comment: What Python implementation are you using? where do Process and Queue come from?

Comment: I'm using python 2.7.2 and Process and Queue come from the library I'll edit the code.

Comment: What is your `a_math_function` doing? If it is CPython, it may block the interpreter via the "Global Interpreter Lock". A known deficit in CPython 2 when it comes to multiprocessing.

Comment: have you benchmarked process creation time compared to the actual work ?

Comment: You're needlessly creating intermediate lists (your newLists). Possibly you're filling RAM causing slow garbage collects. You can fix this just by doing `result = max(a_math_function(x) for x in aList)`.

Comment: I suppose it goes without saying that you are running on multiprocessor hardware?  You won't get any benefit running on a single core machine, hyperthreaded or not.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse since the example uses the multiprocessing module (which uses forks) rather than the threading module (which uses threads) I'd assume the GIL has nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using multiprocessing, try cutting down on the amount of allocation you're doing. You're just filling RAM up with temporary lists (for example the halves of aList you pass the processes, and then the newList lists you create in each process). Quite possibly this is the cause of the slowness as lots of allocation means lots of garbage collection.

Try replacing all your code with this and measuring the speed.

```
def foo():
    print max(a_math_function(x) for x in aList)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a multiprocessing.Pool.map() to distribute the workload between workers and get the result aggregated from it.

See the example here below http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult.successful

Comment: Perhaps just distribute the work in a_math_function like this, and leave the calculation of the max to the top-level process? `max(pool.imap_unordered(a_math_function, aList, 32))`